# c# Socket.RemoteEndPoint shows different port that I'm using to connect

Tags: c#, sockets

I've developed a basic console application that will work as server-client. My general workflow will be like, Server starts clients connect to server and once a client send something the server will receive it and send it to ALL clients. Currently I can do this with my codes but my question is when I send back I've tested Socket.RemoteEndPoint and I saw ports like 65xxx. Like my first client had 65020, second 65021 and so go on. I wonder why this happen since I connect with using 9001 port and listen to 9001 port on my computer. I've done a little bit research but couldn't find a solution to my question. Why do I get these port numbers when I use Socket.RemoteEndPoint? It's okay for me since I don't use firewall or anything while I'm testing to even if the clients connects from another ports it's fine by me as long as its works but what if I have a firewall and I open ONLY 9001 port? Will my client-server based programs work then?

Comment: **Where** are you looking at `RemoteEndPoint`? If you're examining it on the server side, this is *entirely* expected. Clients will usually use an *ephemeral* port at their end, because *their* port doesn't matter.

Comment: I look to RemoteEndPoint on my server side. I type socket.RemoteEndPoint and got this port number. I want to know if I have to open all these ports normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far as the server/firewall on that machine is concerned, what normally matters is the *server* port. You wouldn't normally apply any filtering based on the *client's* port, which as I said in a comment, will normally be an [ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). Under most circumstances, client code will make no effort to specify the local port or IP address and will let the OS pick appropriate values.

The `Socket` class's `LocalEndPoint` and `RemoteEndPoint` use "local" and "remote" to mean "from the perspective of the machine on which this code is running", not "who initiated the connection vs who was connected to".

So on the server, `LocalEndPoint` will give you information about the server end of the connection and `RemoteEndPoint` will give you information about the client end of the connection. Irrespective of who initiated the connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking something else to use but since I learn this I can stick to this method and just open 1 port on my server machine.